# Shiro isPermitted returning false though the permission is defined in the database

Tags: permissions, authorization, shiro, jdbcrealm

I am trying to authorize users based on there permissions provided. The multi level permission string that is provided in the database is as follows :

case:create,update,view;user:create,update,view;asset:create,update,view;account:create,update,view

So when I try to execute    SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("case:create")

it is returning false.

I am really stuck here and need some help. Please let me know how to define permissions for multiple resources and multiple actions.

Thanks for your time.